# Calculating hourly breakdown of minutes in each hour for a period of time

Tags: c#, linq, loops, datetime

I am trying to get a breakdown of minutes in each hour across a period of time. For example, lets say I have two DateTimes like so:

```
DateTime onTime = new DateTime(2019, 11, 6, 6, 30, 0);
DateTime offTime = new DateTime(2019, 11, 6, 10, 45, 0);
```

So there are two DateTimes representing:

```
"2019-11-06 06:30:00"
"2019-11-06 10:45:00"
```

What I am trying to achieve is an hourly breakdown of minutes in each hour for the given period. I would expect that to look something like:

```
int 6 = 30; // Hour 6 = 30 minutes
int 7 = 60; // Hour 7 = 60 minutes
int 8 = 60; // Hour 8 = 60 minutes
int 9 = 60; // Hour 8 = 60 minutes
int 10 = 45; // Hour 10 = 45 minutes
```

I can work out whether to try and use LINQ or just a self referencing iterative function for the desired affect.

Comment: Also, could you please show what you have tried so far? Unless your question isn't about solving the problem, in which case you should rephrase it a little bit.

Comment: I'm not sure how to go about it, otherwise I'd have posted code.

Comment: Are your two dates always in the same day?

Comment: Yes they are on the same day

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only interesting values are the first component and the last component, all others will be `60` no matter what (if there is at least a one hour gap). This is why I would go with the following code:

```cs
public static IEnumerable<int> GetBreakdown(DateTime onTime, DateTime offTime) {
    if (offTime < onTime) {
        throw new ArgumentException();
    }

    // Case where the two times start at the same hour
    if (onTime.Hour == offTime.Hour) {
        yield return offTime.Minute - onTime.Minute;
        yield break;
    }

    // Nominal case
    yield return 60 - onTime.Minute;
    for (int i = onTime.Hour + 1; i < offTime.Hour; i++) {
        yield return 60;
    }
    if (offTime.Minute != 0) {
        yield return offTime.Minute;
    }
}
```

that you could use this way:

```cs
DateTime onTime = new DateTime(2019, 11, 6, 6, 30, 0);
DateTime offTime = new DateTime(2019, 11, 6, 10, 45, 0);
foreach (var value in GetBreakdown(onTime, offTime)) {
    Console.WriteLine(value);
}
// Prints:
// 30
// 60
// 60
// 60
// 45
```

Note that it assumes that both are on the same day, it doesn't consider the `Date` component of the inputs. From here you can easily change the return type from `IEnumerable<int>` to `IEnumerable<(int, int)>` and make the changes to return the hour component in each `yield`.

Comment: Yea I changed the output to KeyValuePair with the Key being the Hour and the Value the minutes.

Comment: You could do it with the even better [`ValueTuple`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.valuetuple?view=netframework-4.8) that lets you return and use tuples with great language support. Just for your information:)